# Trigger key rotation from keyvault key rotation policy using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-keyvault

Having done some research on how to use the rotate now option programmatically for Azure key vault keys. I came up with the script below, but it doesn't appear to work. I was wondering if anyone knew how to rotate keys where a policy already exists.

```
# Install the Azure PowerShell module if not already installed
# Install-Module -Name Az -Force -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser

# Sign in to Azure (use 'Connect-AzAccount' and provide credentials if not signed in)
# Connect-AzAccount

# Variables
$KeyVaultName = "my-kv"

# Get all keys in the Key Vault
$keys = Get-AzKeyVaultKey -VaultName $KeyVaultName

foreach ($key in $keys) {
    # Create a new version of the key
    $newKeyVersion = Update-AzKeyVaultKey -VaultName $KeyVaultName -KeyName $key.Name -KeyVersion $key.KeyIdentifier.Version


    Write-Host "Key rotation completed for $($key.Name). New version: $($newKeyVersion.KeyIdentifier.Version)"
}

Write-Host "Key rotation completed for all keys in $KeyVaultName."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created the keys for sample like below and configured **rotation policy for all the keys:**

***For sample, key1***

[image]

To use the **rotate now option programmatically** for Azure key vault keys, make use of the below PowerShell script:

```
$KeyVaultName = "testrukkv1"

# Get all keys in the Key Vault
$keys = Get-AzKeyVaultKey -VaultName $KeyVaultName

foreach ($key in $keys) {
    # Rotate the key
    $newKeyVersion = Invoke-AzKeyVaultKeyRotation -VaultName $KeyVaultName -KeyName $key.Name

    Write-Host "Key rotation completed for $($key.Name). New version: $($newKeyVersion.Version)"
}

Write-Host "Key rotation completed for all keys in $KeyVaultName."
```

[image]

***Output:***

```
Key rotation completed for key1. New version: xxx
Key rotation completed for key2. New version: xxx
Key rotation completed for key3. New version: xxx
Key rotation completed for all keys in testrukkv1.
```

In the portal, key rotated successfully:

[image]